# What is the best way to do a reference to a function in PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say I can call a method like this: `core::get()`. What is the best way to reference to this method? Everytime I call a function called `get` it should call `core::get()` and pass the same parameters.

All I could come up with was this:

```
function get(){
    call_user_func_array('core::get', func_get_args());
}
```

But it doesn't look very elegant if I compare it to the way I'd solve this in JavaScript:

```
var get = core.get;
```

I'm sure I missed something in PHP, so does anybody has a better solution for this?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: And why can't you simply say `$get = core::get; $get();`? It works for me.

Comment: @PeterRowell I get this: *Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'get'[...]* - what PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost equivalent to your solution that already looks good:

```
$get = function () {
  call_user_func_array('core::get', func_get_args());
};

//usage

$get('arg1','arg2');
```

Note in the case you got a simple function you have could do this:

```
function foo() {} 
$var = 'foo';
$var();  //> same as calling foo();
```

Comment: What exaclty is the difference between declaring a function and passing a function to a variable in PHP?

Comment: If you mean what is an anony function here is the reply: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php I guess you perfectly understand what means "declaring a function"

Comment: I do know what a closure is. But why is this a better solution than mine?

Comment: it's not better, it's just an alternative form

Comment: @dotweb It's a closure in pre-5.3 compatible format. You should accept yes123's answer.